# Функция getDiff которая будет принимать 2 строки и находить все символы, которые различаются в этих строках

Tags: javascript, reactjs, функции, typescript

Написать функцию getDiff , которая будет принимать 2 строки и находить все символы, которые различаются в этих строках. Функция должна вернуть объект.

```js
'Пример работы функции:'
console.log(getDiff('abcd', 'cdfe')); // { array: ['a', 'b', 'f', 'e'] }
console.log(getDiff('abc', 'wbbcc')); // { array: ['a', 'w'] };


'Моя реализация зашла в тупик ((('


function getDiff(a, b) {
  let arrayOfString = a.split('').sort();

  let arrayOfSecondString = b.split('').sort();

  let arr = arrayOfSecondString.find((item, i) => item !== arrayOfString[i]);
  return { arr };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант...

```js
console.log(getDiff('abcd', 'cdfe')); // { array: ['a', 'b', 'f', 'e'] }
console.log(getDiff('abc', 'wbbcc')); // { array: ['a', 'w'] };

function getDiff(a, b) {
    const val = new Set(a + b)
    a = new Set(a)
    for (let s of a) {
        if (b.indexOf(s) > -1) val.delete(s)
    }
    return [...val]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const getDiff = (a, b) => {
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (b.indexOf(a[i]) === -1) {
      arr.push(a[i]);
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    if (a.indexOf(b[i]) === -1) {
      arr.push(b[i]);
    }
  }


  return { arr };
};
```